# Cannot get the desired output in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need to get this output in my python code:
[image: output]

but I am getting index out of range error like this:
[image: error]

here's my code:

```
marks = [['john',80, 90, 76, 82],['katy', 50, 55, 70, 65],['sydney',80,
72, 88, 90]]
marks_c = {}
for i in range(len(marks)):
    name = marks[i][0]
    l = []
    for j in range(2,len(marks[i])):
        print(marks[j][i])
        print(marks_c)

print(marks_c)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you mean `marks[i][j]`, rather than `marks[j][i]`

Comment: when i do marks[j][i] i get a list of numbers and brackets. It is not working.

Comment: Try this: {d[0]: d[1:] for d in marks}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code deliver what you are looking for:

**Code:**

```py
marks = [['john', 80, 90, 76, 82], ['katy', 50, 55, 70, 65], ['sydney', 80, 72, 88, 90]]
marks_c = {}

for entry in marks:
    marks_c[entry.pop(0)] = entry

print(marks_c)

# Upon request of the questioner:
#
# for i in range(len(marks)):
#     name = marks[i][0]
#     l = []
#     for j in range(1,len(marks[i])):
#         l.append(marks[i][j])
#     marks_c[name] = l
```

**Output:**

```py
{'john': [80, 90, 76, 82], 'katy': [50, 55, 70, 65], 'sydney': [80, 72, 88, 90]}
```

Comment: your code works thanks but I actually wanted to know what I need to correct in my own code, so it runs properly. could you give me an idea and help me correct it?

Comment: First of all note @Loocid's comment on your original code: It should read `marks[i][j]` instead of `marks[j][i]`. And second use `range(1,len(marks[i]))` instead of `range(2,len(marks[i]))`. If you then use `l.append(marks[i][j])` in your inner for-loop (assuming this is what you initialized `l` for) and `marks_c[name] = l` in your outer for-loop, then you should get the same result with `print(marks_c)`.

Comment: @SuperMaxLv4 I fixed your code and added it as a comment to my original code. I hope that helps.